# I want to put that when someone writes a word from the black list he is timed out

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

> TypeError: message.member.set_permissions is not a function

```
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("1040666650535542876");
  const dateText = `<t:${Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)}>`
  const black =  client.channels.cache.get("1042833793444216903")
  const i2 = message.author.tag
  var negro2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('2f3136')
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setDescription(` ${message.author.toString()} ha usato una parola blacklistata!\n **Messaggio**: \`${message.content}\`\n **Canale**: ${message.channel} - \`${message.channel.name}\``)
    .addField("Date", `${dateText}`, true)

  var negro = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('2f3136')
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setDescription(` ${message.author.toString()}, Non usare parole blacklistate o verrai mutato!\n **Messaggio**: \`${message.content}\``)
  let blacklisted = [ 'discord.gg','https://discord.com/invite', 'discord.com','https://dsc.gg/', 'dsc.gg', ];
  if (message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
    return`your text`
  }
  let utente24 = guild.members.cache.get(i2);
  let foundInText = false;
  for (var i in blacklisted) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
  }
  if (foundInText) {
    await message.member.set_permissions(message.author, SEND_MESSAGES=false, ADD_REACTIONS=false)    message.delete();
    message.author.send({ embeds: [negro] })
    black.send({ embeds: [negro2] })

  }
})
```

```
    await message.member.set_permissions(message.author, SEND_MESSAGES=false, ADD_REACTIONS=false)
```

I want to put that when someone writes a word from black list he is timed out

Comment: member.set_permissions is a discord.py method, and does not work with discord.js. In discord.js I believe you would have to change the role of the member.

Answer (score 0):

member.set_permissions is a discord.py method.
use this instead:

```js
await message.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.author, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: false,
      ADD_REACTIONS: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I have another error:

 **TypeError: message.channel.updateOverwrite is not a function**

Comment: what version is your discord.js

Comment: its's 13.12.0 version

Comment: all my bot is in 13.12.0

Comment: i have updated the code. try it again.

Comment: And if instead of removing the person’s permission, how do I get them to timeout?